# Deciphering names from Spanish marriage certificate

Tags: palaeography, marriage-records, spain

I am trying to decipher two names on this Spanish Marriage certificate:

[image: Scan of marriage certificate]

This is what I do know:

- Manuel Muñoz **Guilloume**
- **Aurosa** Pérez Arellano

The two items in bold I am not sure about.

Comment: note in [spanish.se] we have a [specific tag](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identificación-de-término) for these kind of questions from Spanish texts.

Comment: The name is most probably _Aurora_. It is a common name in Spain, or it used to be in the old days.

Comment: I read it as Guillorme.

Comment: I read it as _Guillerme_. In Geneanet, there are records with this name in Corella, Navarra, Spain.

Comment: @gparis That sounds promising!

Answer (score 3):

When I have doubts between potential surnames due to the writing and there is no available second source, I try to look to statistics to the most probable surname.

You can you to this webpage of statistics of names and surnames in Spain: https://www.ine.es/widgets/nombApell/index.shtml

In our case and the different proposed wordings:

- Guillorme: there is heavy incidence of this surname in Basque Country, Navarra, Rioja, Soria and some in Zaragoza. Looks Navarra as core area and the person is born in Navarra.
- Guillerme: there is evidence of this surname in Basque Country in Vizcaya. The surname is related to the mother of the person, who is natural from Navarra (Corella) which is not a close by city (is also important to know the time of the record).

Based on this, I think the right one is Guillorme, although Guillerme cannot be discarded, but the probability will be extremely low.

I tested Guilforme and Guillermo (asuming wrong writting). Guillermo can be as well probable surname, and it having bigger incidence in Navarra than Guillorme but it requires to be a mistake int he written (which is possible, sometime frequent)

My guess:

- High probability => Guillorme
- To keep in mind looking for a second source => Guillerme, Guillermo

In order to progress I see 2 options:

- Look for another source of the same person
- Look for a census or similar document in Corella and confirm which surname is actually more common in Corella.

Anyhow, Guillorme is for me an "almost match"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mention Spanish Census records, How do we go about searching those?

Comment: Well, the question is when are you looking for. At the end you are looking for statistics and likely whatever year is enough. You can directly contact the town hall office directly (and likely they might ansewr you directly) or give you acess to a census on their  hands: http://censoarchivos.mcu.es/CensoGuia/archivodetail.htm?id=40184 (this is the link to Corella info)

Comment: Or, if you are looking for older archives, which might not be digitalized, you might need to look for Navarra's historical archive, likely a bigger effort. The source will be "Archivo Real y General de Navarra": http://www.navarra.es/home_es/Temas/Turismo+ocio+y+cultura/Archivos/Archivos/Archivo+General+de+Navarra/

Comment: Finally, it might be an easier option to look for the birth certificate of the person, if the person might have born after 1871 you can request from the town hall directly the information here: https://sede.mjusticia.gob.es/es/tramites

Comment: Archives from the parishes can be accessed in the archives, but again, not digitalized. Likely available form XIX century an before:https://www.iglesianavarra.org/diocesis/archivo-diocesano-2/

Comment: If you tell me the year I might be able to provide a more accurate feedback.

Comment: I have asked a question here https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/18208/8882 that is more suited to this Census data approach. 

Answer (score 2):

this is my guess:

..natural de Corella, vecina de Corella, hijo legítimo de D. Manuél Muñoz Guíllorme y de Dª Aurora Pérez Arellano y a Dª Teresa Marcilla _ienrolas, de Veintiseis años, de estado soltera, sus labores y que nació el día 1 de ...
natural de: born place, vecida de: actual home, legítimo: born under marriage, estado soltera: single - not married, sus labores: house wife.

In Spain you get surname from father and mother, so name1 surname1 suname11 marry name2 surname2 surname22, childs will be name2 suname1 surname2, ... No clue about Teresa's second surname. D. = Don > Mr., Dª = Doña > Mrs.