# Locating Birth Certificates in Spain using Census Info

Tags: birth-records, census-records, spain

I want to try and obtain accurate details about my Great Grandparents birth (ie. obtain certificates) on my Grandfathers side. My mother has provided photos of them to me and told me a bit about them.

### Great Grandfather

Name: Miguel Torres Jimenez

I understand that he was born about 1883 in Osuna, Seville, Andalucia, Spain.

His parents (my Great Great Grandparents) are:

- José María Torres Garcia (Osuna, Seville, Andalucia, Spain)
- Isabel Jimenez Montero (Same location)

### Great Grandmother

Name: Mariana Dominguez Morales

Her parents are:

- Manuel Dominguez Muñoz (Osuna, Seville, Andalucia, Spain)
- Mariana Morales Rueda (Same location)

I understand that she was born about 1890 in the same area and that she might have died about 1945.

---

My late Grandfather was born in 1913 in La Roda de Andalucia and I have his actual birth certificate. I contacted the Civil Registry Office there and they kindly located it and sent it to me in the post. So I gleaned much of the above from his certificate:

[image: Certificate Info]

But I can’t find my Great Grandparents certificates. For this question I am limiting the topic to **Birth**. I wondered that there may be some info in Census Records in Spain that might assist in working things out. I have asked for a search of 1883 and 1890 etc. and have no responses so far.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, are you familiar with Spanish surname customs? For example, Miguel Torres Jimenez gets "Torres" from his father and "Jimenez" from his mother, so his parents would be SomeMan Torres Something and SomeWoman Jimenez Something. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_naming_customs

Comment: @shoover yes I am aware of how the names work. But I should be able to find birth records as I know their full names and approx info of birth etc.

Answer (score 3):

I looked in FamilySearch and you have quite good resources to find. I would suggest to not start with the census, but with the cementry register, as you know around which date your great grandmother died.

The list of resources in FamilySearch is this one: https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=100&placeId=1115843&query=%2Bplace%3A%22Spain%2C%20Andaluc%C3%ADa%2C%20Sevilla%2C%20Osuna%22&subjectsOpen=1115844-50,1445905-50,1531141-50

The cementry is this one: https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/2821194

Concerning census/registry of inhabitants, I would go as second step.

Unfourtunately, women's suffrage was fully approved in Spain in 1931. That means that any census in Spain before that date will not contain your great grandmother. However, depending on the city, the register of inhabitants (called "padrón" in spanish) might contain women. However, the brothers of your great grandmother will be present. Just wanted to mention that in terms of searching strategy.

When addressing the census, also take into account the voting age (over 18 years), so you should look in census over 1901 for your great granfather. Your great grandmother was 18 around 1908, but you do not have any idea about her brothers... so I would look around 1910-1920.

I looked in FamilySearch and I found that actually several census and reigsters of inhabitants (padrón) here: https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/2821195?availability=Family%20History%20Library

I also double checked and they are accessible from internet (you can see the images) but they are not digitalized (so it will be a real search around several hundred of pages...)

I checked the "padrón" and I found that women and men were included but it looks that the minimum age for being included was around 14 years old. That's making your starting time around 1897.

Be aware as well that, for some reason, sometimes the age in the census was not accurate.

Based on that, I would suggest the following:

- Grandfather: use the census from 1906 to 1916, starting in the latest year. Once you locate the street in the first one it will be easy for you to locate the person in the census (you go straight away to the street). You might need to find 2 streets, when he was living wiht his parents (your great-great parents) and when he was living wiht your great granmother (btw, both locations might be the same...). With that street you can go to "padrón" or "census" and find everybody living there. I do recommend starting wiht census because there will be half of the people to look through.
- Grandmother: start with her as second step, once you know the places your granfather was living. Depending on your result above you might be able to use "padrón" to find her or you might need to look for the brothers of your grandmother. Problem is that she was 26 in the last census, and she might not have married by that time (so grandfather might not help wiht grandmother, that's why grandfather search first is the best strategy).

Another research idea is to contact the cementry of Osuna, they might have a registry of death and might find your parents (with the exact death date you will be able to request a certificate and later on finding the right location)

Hope this helps... if I think in any other strategy I will try to include here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have since learned that they were in Valencia by the time of their deaths. So I have put together a letter to the registry office in Valencia with approx year of death for my Great Grandfather.

Comment: The town hall of Valencia offers a web interface to look for buried people inside their cementeries. I tried to look for your great grand parents and I did not found any match. However, I found somebody with the same surname that one of your granparents will have "Torres Domínguez". Do you know if great granparents had more that one kid? (website: https://www.valencia.es/cas/cementerios/localizacion-de-difuntos)

Comment: Note, likely your greatparents are buried in Osuna but they likely died in Valencia. So I think that asking to the cementry of Osuna is still a good strategy. Concerning Valencia registry my experience with them is that, for old records, they will not make the effort if you do not have accurate information.

Comment: I made a check of Torres and Dominguez surnames and they are not highly common in Valencia compared to other regions. Is very likely that the 2 persons in Valencia cementry are your relatives. Do you need help with the spanish administration?

Comment: I only just posted my letter so I will see if I get a reply. I don’t know how to go about writing to osuna cemetery. I will update here in few weeks.

Comment: They had three children. Miguel. Manolo and my Grandad Enrique (I have his death certificate and see his grave. I was at his funeral in Spain with my mum and her family).

Comment: So... there is a buried person in Valencia called Manuel Torres Domínguez. In Spain usually Manuel are called Manolo. So it is very likely you great uncle. Go to this page https://www.valencia.es/cas/cementerios/localizacion-de-difuntos, he died on 13th October 1983

Comment: For Osuna cementery you have here the contact details, the have a generic town hall address: http://www.osuna.es/es/ayuntamiento/delegaciones/Cementerio/?urlBack=

Comment: Just read you "post a letter" to Valencia. Do you mean you have sent a physical one? There are phone numbers and mail interface wiht them (which depending on the town hall you might have different level of usefullnes) for Valencia the contact details are here: https://www.mjusticia.gob.es/BUSCADIR/ServletControlador?apartado=buscadorMunicipios&municipio=46250&nombre_municipio=&nombre_partido=&lang=es_es&tipo=RC&origen=

Comment: However, there is an official way to request this information from the town halls, for death registers they are obliged to answer (at least to Spaniards) and it usually take less than a week: https://sede.mjusticia.gob.es/es/tramites/certificado-defuncion

Comment: I can help you on your research, seen your profile and the link to your company, I can contact you using the contact form and I will help you with the search.

Comment: I have already spoken with Manolo's family and they informed me about his death "25 Mar 2001 Seville, Andalucia, Spain". Thanks for your willingness to help. And yes, I have sent a normal letter in the post to Valencia.

Comment: Hi! I had a reply from Valencia Registry Office and they sent me my Great Grandfathers death certificate! He died on 23 January 1965 at the Hospital in Valencia. According to the certificate he was burried (enterramiento) in "Cemeterio de Valencia".

Comment: That's great news! With the death certificate in hands now you should know the exact date he was born and actually where he was born. Even legacy death certificates contain information about descendants.

Comment: I made a quick check in Valencia (https://www.valencia.es/cas/cementerios/localizacion-de-difuntos) and there is no Miguel Torres any longer in the cementry. Which can mean that he was transferred to another cementry or the renting of the burial was stopped. They might have legacy documents, you can contact them here: oficinadpd@valencia.es

Comment: Thanks for looking. I sent letter in the post to Oficina de Cementeris, Camí vell de Picassent, S/N (junt a Tanatori Municipal) - 46017 – València.

Comment: They just replied by email - and provided the details about my Great Grandfathers burial on 25th January 1965.

Comment: Update: The Civil Guard in Madrid just email me his miliarty papers so I now have his date of birth, his parents town and the fact that he was already married by 1902 when he joined the civil guard.